# Why my website display only one image on iPad?

Tags: html, ios, css, image, ipad

I have problems with my website. There is displayed only one (first) image on website even if futher images will be this same (I mean this same src, just like to first one).

Website has section with image background.

Code:

```
#kafelobrazintro { 
background: url(../images/introtablet.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; 
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
position: relative; 
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
overflow:hidden;
}
```

This is section with working img but even if I copy this css to another section, website will still display only one img.

Images on website are lower than 2 MPX, resolution: 1024 x 614 px, size less than 100kb.

If u have iPad check my website and get know what Im talking about :> Website display only first img :?

Why its not working?

Adress: http://www.badzlepszy.pl/Nebiolo/

Comment: First of all, what do you mean if you copy this css. Do you change the css class name? Do you change the background url? I'm sorry if these questions are insulting, but we can never be sure here on SO.

Comment: yep...

I keep bg url, to try display this same img, but even this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `background-attachment: fixed;`. If you remove `fixed` the background images work.

Use media queries to change this property at the appropriate window sizes.

Comment: I removed fixed attribute in background-attachment butstill not working..

You can check modificated version at: http://www.badzlepszy.pl/Nebiolo/


Why its not working?

Comment: @Lethysek you only removed `fixed` for the first image. For example, see CSS for `#kafelobraz1`.

Comment: There is another css for tablets <link media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" href="css/tablet.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> and in this css, fidex is removed for all images, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Still didnt solve the problem. First image on iPad displays, but futher ones dont.

If u have iPad u can check at: [website](http://www.badzlepszy.pl/Nebiolo/)

I created tableb.css just for iPads:

```
<link media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" href="css/tablet.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

CSS for img section in tablets:

```
#kafelobrazintro { 
background: url(../images/introtablet.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat; 
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
position: relative; 
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
overflow:hidden;
}

#kafelobraz1 { 
background: url(../images/logomzblue.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;  
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
position: relative; 
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was here with a little bit of difference. My div-s with background images were empty ( no text and no html content )

The solution here was adding: min-width: 1024; to these div-s.

( I tested your site with iPad Air and iPad 4th on http://www.browserstack.com/ and looks good )